# Orthogonal projection $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $\Pi$ be the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that contains $\textbf0,\textbf j,\textbf k$. Show that the orthogonal projection $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $\Pi$ is a linear map.

I'm more interested in finding this orthogonal projection, as I still don't understand what exactly is mean't by that, while showing its linearity I think is quite easy.

Now, this plane will be given by $\textbf x \cdot \textbf i=0$ right? Thus, the projection I think will be given by $\textbf x \cdot \textbf i + t=0$, where $t$ is chosen such that $\textbf x + t\textbf i$ lies on $\Pi$. If I'm right, then linearity of this map follows from linearity of dot product. Thus, am I right or it doesn't make much sense? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thus, the projection I think will be given by $\textbf x \cdot \textbf i + t=0$

This is somewhat confused! The projection is $\alpha(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{x} + t\textbf{i}$ , where $t = -\textbf{x.i}$. You can check that

1. $\alpha(\textbf{x}).\textbf{i} = 0$, so that $\alpha(\textbf{x})$ lies in $\Pi$;
2. $\alpha(\textbf{x}) - \textbf{x}$ is orthogonal to $\Pi$.